# Binding to a list which is inside a hierarchy of custom Views in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, binding, xamarin.forms

Below is the scenario.

I have a list inside a Custom xyzContentView which is inside another Custom abcContentView. The abcContentView is added as custom Control inside a ContentPage. I have a Model which has 2 lists(HeadQuarter, Person). How can i bind Person list to the listView which is inside the xyzContentView. Also how can i bind the HeadQuarter list to the content page items which are just plan labels (its not a list).
I am using MVVM so how can i bind the Person List with the SampleViewCell  using the ParentViewModel. And bind HeadQuarter List to Labels(Not a listview).

Parent Page(Page1.xaml)

```
<Content Page>
    ....
    ....
    <controls:xyzContentView />
</Content Page>
```

xyzContentView.xaml

```
<ContentView>
    ....
    ....
    <customControl:abcContentView />
</ContentView>
```

abcContentView.xaml

```
<ContentView>
    ....
    ....
    <ListView
            x:Name       ="listView"
            HasUnevenRows="true">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:SampleViewCell>
                    </local:SampleViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
</ContentView>
```

SampleViewCell.xaml

```
<ViewCell>
<ViewCell.View>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition
                Width="*">
            </ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding LastName}" />
    </Grid>
</ViewCell.View>
</ViewCell>
```

Let say i have a model as below:
Company Data:

```
public class Company
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public List<HeadQuarter> HD { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class HeadQuarter
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just let the ParentViewModel class provide the Person list through a public property? That said, it is unfortunately not really possible to say anything more besides pure speculation, because you did not mention how your viewmodel(s) relate to your views/pages/UI elements and your underlying data model, nor whether you already tried what i just mentioned in the beginning of my comment and what the particular problems were. Your further questions about bindings are also not answerable, as those are lacking any information necessary for understanding your situation.

Comment: In my opinion, it is better to ask those questions about VMs and about bindings as different questions here on StackOverflow, as it probably will lower your chances to get an answer at all if you lump different questions into one "combo question". Although all your questions have "binding" in common, their respective answers might possibly be quite different and more related to your individual design and structure of your views, view models and models...